# Graphing two cumulative distributions in Stata

Tags: statistics, distribution, stata, kernel-density

I'm trying this code (just below), Stata seems to read it -- it does not show any errors --, but it does not generate any variables. Here it is:

`cumul price if dummy==1, gen(cprice1)`

`cumul price if dummy==0, gen (cprice2)`

`line cprice1 cprice2 price`

Could you guys help me? I could graph two kernel density distributions with a condition of "if" for the dummy, with a similar code, in which I stored the results for latter graphing them -- following the help files in Stata. But I could not do this with the cumulative distributions.

Comment: The example in `help cumul` works just fine. Try that. It's difficult to figure out what is wrong if you do not give a reproducible example.

Comment: `distplot` from the *Stata Journal* supports cumulative distribution plots. `search distplot` in Stata for download locations, and choose the most recent.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not generating the variables. I wanted to understand why.

Comment: Our problem is that you don't give a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to store the variables, `cdfplot` will do the trick. If not, `cumul` seems to work just fine:

```
sysuse auto, clear

/* Without Storing Variables */
ssc install cdfplot
cdfplot price, by(foreign) saving(cdfplot, replace)

/* With Variable Creation */ 
cumul price if foreign == 0, gen(cprice0)
cumul price if foreign == 1, gen(cprice1)

tw conn cprice* price, sort connect(J J) ms(none none) saving(cumulplot, replace)

/* Compare the two methods */
graph combine cdfplot.gph cumulplot.gph
```